# How to load modules on Synology NAS on boot?

Tags: bash, synology, kernel-modules

I have a Synology NAS (DSM 6.2.4) and I would like to load usbserial.ko and cp210x.ko on boot.

When I run:

```
sudo insmod /lib/modules/usbserial.ko
sudo insmod /lib/modules/cp210x.ko
```

The drivers work correctly, but when I reboot they are no longer loaded. Is there a way to get these to load on boot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, first ssh into your Synology NAS then create a script here `/usr/local/etc/rc.d/` like with `vi` with `sudo vi /usr/local/etc/rc.d/load-modules.sh` put this inside

```
#!/bin/sh

case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Loading usbserial.ko and cp210x.ko modules..."
        insmod /lib/modules/usbserial.ko
        insmod /lib/modules/cp210x.ko
        ;;
    stop)
        echo "Unloading usbserial.ko and cp210x.ko modules..."
        rmmod cp210x
        rmmod usbserial
        ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop}"
        exit 1
        ;;
esac

exit 0
```

then give it the execute permission `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/etc/rc.d/load-modules.sh`

You can test if your script work like that `sudo /usr/local/etc/rc.d/load-modules.sh start`

Then restart your Synology NAS, now it is loaded at startup.